# External Hard drive with magnet built into the enclosure

Tags: external-hard-drive

I recently bought two Hitachi HLSMPUA3201ABB external Hard drives. They come with a USB key attached to the enclosure *with a magnet*. It's not a very strong magnet but I can't help wondering whether the drive would last longer without it. Should I consider returning it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't damage your HDD, don't even give it a second thought.

See [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/116572/busting_the_biggest_pc_myths.html) for reasons why.

> The only magnets powerful enough to scrub data from a drive platter
>   are laboratory degaussers or those used by government agencies to wipe
>   bits off media. "In the real world, people are not losing data from
>   magnets," says Bill Rudock, a tech-support engineer with hard-drive
>   maker Seagate. "In every disk," notes Rudock, "there's one heck of a
>   magnet that swings the head."

There are [magnets inside the hard drive](http://www.reuk.co.uk/Hard-Disk-Drive-Magnets-For-Wind-Turbines.htm) also and are not shielded in any way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would have realised if I stopped to think. Guess I was being over-paranoid about my fifty bucks. :)

Comment: Don't they put [mu-metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) around the motors in a hard drive to route the magnetic field away from the platters?

Comment: Sensible people are cautious with their money. Its worth asking if you're not sure. Imagine if the answer had gone the other way and you hadn;t asked :-)

Comment: The armature that moves the heads on a hard drive uses a very powerful magnet on both sides of the voice coil, they are not shielded, and they sit very close to the platters, Joe is right, it takes a super magnet to have any effect on data...http://www.reuk.co.uk/Hard-Disk-Drive-Magnets-For-Wind-Turbines.htm

Answer (score 2):

It will be fine. Harddrives even *contain* magnets.